# Inverted dose-response variables

Tags: regression, predictive-models, prediction, logistic-curve, dose-response

*Context*:

Often when we carry out dose-response modelling we want to estimate the dose required to elicit a predetermined response (i.e. response ~ dose). Typically this is done with inverse regression techniques (i.e. [after-fitting / reparameterisation](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0146021)), but sometimes these impose constraints or come with a greater degree of uncertainty.

*Question*:

Is there any statistical reason that we shouldn't instead just swap the terms (I.e. dose ~ response), if the goal of the exercise is fit a model with the most accurate predictions?

I understand that it is very unorthodox (at least) to suggest that an applied treatment is dependent on the response and goes against the underlying theory but is there any mathematical reason we should not do this if it gives more accurate predictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason not to do it.

Nonlinear regression (as usually implemented and performed) is based on the assumption that the distribution of the differences between the actual Y values and the predicted Y values (the curve) is Gaussian. If that assumption is reasonable, then it is unlikely that the distribution of the difference between actual concentrations and the predicted concentrations would be Gaussian. If the assumption is far off, then so are the results.

It is easy enough to fit the curve conventionally and then interpolate the values you need.

Comment: What about with models like SVMs?

Comment: What does SVM stand for?

Comment: Support Vector Machine

Comment: Non-linear regression does **not** assume that the residuals are Gaussian! That is an assumption of least-squares, which can be used in some non-linear cases.

Comment: @Galen. Thanks. I added a clause to my answer that this assumption (normal residuals) is the basis of commonly used nonlinear regression methods (but other methods could be developed)